# Cannot install or uninstall anything after update to jellyfish

Tags: apt, 22.04

No matter what I try to install or uninstall, I get blocked. When I try to do it via Terminal, I always get the exact same message referencing `ms-teams`:

```
$ sudo apt remove zoom
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/ms-teams.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

this is the content of the ms-teams.list file

> deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ms-teams.gpg]
> https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main

Any ideas on how I can overcome this? I need to update a bunch of apps after upgrading to Jellyfish.

Comment: check you apt sources, you may have a duplicate entry for teams, and/or you may just need to remove the signed-by portion

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the content of the apt sources `.list` file that references the Teams repository? The error is saying that something is misconfigured, so seeing how your source is set up will make it possible to offer a solution 

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @matigo. i just added the contents of the ms-teams.list file. i wonder if i should just delete that file?

Comment: try just removing the signed-by option in brackets, and see if that solves

Comment: boom. that solved it. thanks @ElefantPhace!

Answer (score 0):

try just removing the signed-by option in brackets, and see if that solves –
ElefantPhace

Answer (score 0):

Check you apt sources, you may have a duplicate entry for teams, and/or you may just need to remove the signed-by portion such as if your `ms-teams.list` looks like:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ms-teams.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
```

remove the `signed-by` option

```
deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
```